# Replace only few characters from list python

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list which is of the following format:

```
[ '2013,june,25,11,img1.ams.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2M_Mac_x86,84.83.189.112,3', '2013,june,25,11,img1.ams.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2MInstallerExtractor.exe,85.164.14.248,6', '2013,june,25,11,img1.syd.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2MCoreInstExtractor.exe,99.245.80.126,19']
```

I need to replace only the first three commas with '-' for each element of the list i.e the list should look like this:

```
[ '2013-june-25-11,img1.ams.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2M_Mac_x86,84.83.189.112,3', '2013-june-25-11,img1.ams.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2MInstallerExtractor.exe,85.164.14.248,6', '2013-june-25-11,img1.syd.expertcity.com,/builds/g2m/1172/G2MCoreInstExtractor.exe,99.245.80.126,19']
```

I tried to use replace but it ends up replacing all ',' with '-'

```
mylist = [x.replace(",","-") for x in mylist]
```

I do not want to use regex because the order in the list might change over time. 
Please suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :  `x.replace(",","-",3)`

`str.replace` has a third optional argument `count`.

help on `str.replace`:

```
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
```

> Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new.  If the optional argument **count** is given, only the
>   first **count occurrences** are replaced.

Comment: Hi, if i need to replace the fourth and fifth comma with ':' and the first three commas with '-', is there a way to specify range values also ?